# Вопрос про календарь

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать что-то на подобии:
по нажатию кнопки показывать календарь, в котором будет выделена текущая дата, если выбирать предыдущие даты, осуществлялось какое-то действие(не важно какое).

Как это можно реализовать?(какие компоненты, библиотеки и т.п.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте стандартный виджет [CalendarView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) , который помимо прочих имеет метод `setOnDateChangeListener()`, который привязывает к календарю метод обратного вызова для возврата выбранной в календаре даты.

[пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/calendarview.php)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Какие еще варианты могут быть ?

Comment: еще есть множество [подключаемых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=calendarview+android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)